# Append or replace data of store by non-id field

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I've a store that pulls data from a server using a proxy config

```
Ext.define("MyStore", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.Rest'],

    config: {
        model: "MyModel",
        autoLoad: false,

        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: '.../url/...',
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer userToken'
            },

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'prop',
                totalProperty: 'count',
                successProperty: 'success'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Given that the proxy invokes a services that gives updates based on the current date, I want to keep the storage records, and append the new results.
Finally, if I want to be able to replace the records that has the same value in a specific field (code).

Comment: The only solution is to define that "code" field as your ID field. Data is ALWAYS replaced based on the ID field, that's industry standard. You shouldn't do otherwise, or it'll make your code a total mess no one wants to maintain.

Comment: Thanks Alexander! I'm now using an ajax request and then perform the update manually in the store.